# How to define a general vector in an affine space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I know how an affine space is defined: a vector sub space, with another vector from the original space, which isn’t in the sub space. Additionally, I know how to write a general form of a vector within a vector space using the space’s span,however, how do I write the general vector within an affine space?

Comment: Just write $v_0+w$ where $v_0$ is the given vector not *necessarily* in the given subspace and $w$ is from the given subspace.

Comment: Thank you very very much!